# Ability to mark dated answers as deprecated

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

It is common while reading posts on the site to come across answers that are several years old and contain deprecated code.  Currently, there is not a visible indicator that warns viewers that code is deprecated.  Would it be possible to include some type of icon or note at the top of answers to quickly indicate to viewers that code is deprecated?

Comment: Well...if a user *blindly* plugs and chugs the result of an accepted answer that *is* dated, then who's really at fault?  What would marking an answer as "deprecated" really benefit?

Comment: You can just edit outdated answers.

Answer (score 9):

An answer is only deprecated when there is no version or release identifier to go with it. If it has that identifier then it is both in context and potentially correct (if it hasn't been marked as the answer).

So if you retag (and/or edit) a question with the correct version information then the problem is solved.